# How to make the argument as optional in bash?

Tags: bash, functions

In below function with 9 arguments:

```
SUM() { 
    echo "The sum is $(($1+$2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9))"
}
```

I want to make the **second arguments to the next(3..9) become a optional arguments**.

When I call the function with 2 arguments I get error:

```
SUM 3 8
bash: 3+8+++++++: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
```

**Note BOLD**: first argument and second argument are **force arguments** and not optional for function. I only want second arguments to the next is optional and when I call the function less than 2 args the function must return no result.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you won't pass arguments with spaces:

```
sum() {  
[[ -n $2 ]] && echo $(( $(tr ' ' '+' <<<"$@") ))
}
```

Effect:

```
$ sum 1 2 3
6
```

Explanation:

1. `<<<"some string"` feeds in only `"some string"` as the input. Think of it as shorthand for `echo "some string" |`. It is called a [Here String](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings).
2. [`"$@"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html) expands into all the positional parameters, separated by spaces.  It is equivalent to `"$1 $2 ..."`.
3. Hence, `tr ' ' '+' <<<"$@"` outputs `"$1+$2+$3..."`, which is evaluated by the outer `$(( ))`.
4. `[[ -n $2 ]]` tests if the second parameter is non-empty. You could replace `[[ -n $2 ]] &&` with `[[ -z $2 ]] ||`.

---

Another way:

```
sum() {
[[ -n $2 ]] && (IFS=+; echo $(( $* )))
}
```

Explanation:

1. `$*` is just like `$@`, except that the parameters are not separated by spaces, but by the first character of the [Internal Field Separator (`IFS`)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF). With `IFS=+`, it expands to "$1+$2+...". See [What is the difference between $* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41595/70524)
2. We set `IFS` in a subshell (note the surrounding parentheses) so that the main shell isn't affected. `IFS` is, by default: `\t\n` (space, tab, newline). This is an alternative to using `local` variables.

---

Now to answer your question:

You can use a [default value](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for any variable or parameter.
Either:

```
SUM() { 
 echo "The sum is $(($1+$2+${3:-0}+${4:-0}+${5:-0}+${6:-0}+${7:-0}+${8:-0}+${9:-0}))" || false
}
```

Or:

```
SUM() { 
 echo "The sum is $(($1+$2+${3:=0}+${4:=0}+${5:=0}+${6:=0}+${7:=0}+${8:=0}+${9:=0}))" || false
}
```

Comment: Nifty! I know comments aren't meant for gratuitous compliments and thanks, but this solution is just ... wicked! :-)

Answer (score 17):

Have a look at the `shift` operator. It will shift arguments 2 and onward to positions 1 and onward, discarding argument 1.

```
sum () {
    local total=0;
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        total=$(($total + $1))
        shift
    done
    echo $total
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a recursive definition which terminates when `sum` is invoked without arguments. We make use of the fact that `test` without arguments evaluates to `false`.

```
sum () {
    test $1 && echo $(( $1 + $(shift; sum $@) )) || echo 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SUM () {
 [ $# -lt "2" ] && return 1
 for par in $@; do
   local sum=`expr $sum + $par`
 done
 echo $sum
 return 0
}

SUM 3 4 5
SUM 3 4 5 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5
```

This will output 12 and 30.

`$@` refers to parameter, `$#` returns the number of parameter, in this case 3 or 11.

Tested on linux redhat 4

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a little loop:

```
sum(){
    t=0;
    for i in "$@"; do t=$((t + i )); done
    echo $t;
}
```

Personally though, I'd just use `perl` or `awk` instead:

```
sum(){
 echo "$@" | perl -lane '$s+=$_ for @F; print $s'
}
```

or

```
sum(){
 echo "$@" | awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){k+=$i} print k}'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 0 as default values for $1 to $9:

```
SUM() { 
    echo "The sum is $((${1:-0}+${2:-0}+${3:-0}+${4:-0}+${5:-0}+${6:-0}+${7:-0}+${8:-0}+${9:-0}))"
}
```

From `man bash`:

```
${parameter:-word}
    Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion
    of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is
    substituted.
```

Examples:

```
$ SUM
```

The sum is 0

```
$ SUM 1 2
```

The sum is 3

```
$ SUM 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The sum is 9

---

Same output with awk:

```
SUM() {
  echo -e ${@/%/\\n} | awk '{s+=$1} END {print "The sum is " s}'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also my own solution I tried it and found:

```
SUM() { 
    echo "The sum is $(($1+$2+$[$3]+$[$4]+$[$5]+$[$6]+$[$7]+$[$8]+$[$9]))"
 }

$ SUM 4 6 5
The sum is 15
```

But [@muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/522280/283843) is good.

Comment: +1: Interesting usage of two [arithmetic expansions](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_05) to evaluate empty parameters to zero.

Comment: @muru thanks, but in this case [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/522296/283843) we don't use more than 9 arguments and we have to use group of arguments to pass more than 9. thank you for your answer that's perfect.